# Comparing simple products of grouped/configurable products in Magento2

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to compare simple products that belong to a grouped/configurable product?

We are using configurables/grouped products in Magento2
The associated simple products are set „not visible individually“ in the Backend (Visibility-Attribute).
We need to be able to use the compare funktion for the associated simple products without changing the visibility for those.

Thanks for your help!